# d3 js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of null

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

Всем привет! Я использую d3 js первый раз для отрисовки агрегационного графика, и мне нужно в нем обновить данные по нажатию на кнопку. Для отрисовки графики я использую синтаксис классов и вызываю и метод первоначальной отрисовки и далее метод обновления данных.

И при первом нажатии на кнопку все отлично, данные обновляются, но если повторно нажать на кнопку и вызвать этот же метод появляется данная ошибка в консоли Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of null

Опытным путем выяснил, что переменная this.svg после первого обновления данных становиться null, не могу разобраться в чем причина.

Благодарю за помощь!

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import { brush} from 'd3';

export default class AggregationChart {
  margin: Record<string, any>;
  w: Number;
  h: Number;
  width: Number;
  height: Number;
  from: Number;
  to: Number;
  data: Array<Object>;
  svg: any;
  x: any;
  y: any;
  brush: any;
  g: any;
  labelL: any;
  labelR: any;
  brushg: any;
  gBrush: any;
  handle: any;
  xBrush: any;

  constructor(data: any) {
    this.margin = { top: 30, right: 2, bottom: 0, left: 0 };
    this.w = 800;
    this.h = 85;
    this.width = this.w - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
    this.height = this.h - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;
    this.from = 0;
    this.to = 365;
    this.data = data;
    this.svg = null;
    this.x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, this.width]);
    this.y = d3.scaleLinear().range([this.h, 0]);
    this.brush = null;
    this.g = null;
    this.labelL = null;
    this.labelR = null;
    this.gBrush = null;
    this.handle = null;
    this.xBrush = null;
  }

  showChart() {
    var x = this.x;
    var y = this.y;

    var area = d3
      .area()
      .x(function (d) {
        return x(d.x);
      })
      .y0(this.h)
      .y1(function (d) {
        return y(d.y);
      });

    this.svg = d3
      .select('#area')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', this.w)
      .attr('height', this.h + 30)
      .append('g')
      .attr(
        'transform',
        'translate(' + this.margin.left + ',' + this.margin.top + ')'
      );

 
    x.domain(
      d3.extent(this.data, function (d) {
        return d.x;
      })
    );
    y.domain([
      0,
      d3.max(this.data, function (d) {
        return d.y;
      }),
    ]);


    this.svg
      .append('path')
      .data([this.data])
      .attr('class', 'area filled')
      .attr('id', 'areafield')
      .attr('d', area);

    // gradient for back chart
    var svgDefs = this.svg.append('defs');

    var mainGradient = svgDefs
      .append('linearGradient')
      .attr('id', 'mainGradient');

    mainGradient.append('stop').attr('class', 'stop-left').attr('offset', '0');

    mainGradient
      .append('stop')
      .attr('class', 'stop-right')
      .attr('offset', '100%');

    this.svg.selectAll('#mainGradient').attr('gradientTransform', 'rotate(90)');

    this.drawBrush(50, 80);
  }

  updateDataChart(data) {
    console.log('update chart');
    console.log(data);

    var x = this.x;
    var y = this.y;

    var svg = d3
      .select('#area')
      .select('#svgarea')
      .attr('width', this.w)
      .attr('height', this.h + 30)
      .select('#gselect')
      .attr(
        'transform',
        'translate(' + this.margin.left + ',' + this.margin.top + ')'
      );

    // define the area
    var area = d3
      .area()
      .x(function (d) {
        return x(d.x);
      })
      .y0(this.h)
      .y1(function (d) {
        return y(d.y);
      });

    // scale the range of the data
    x.domain(
      d3.extent(data, function (d) {
        return d.x;
      })
    );
    y.domain([
      0,
      d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.y;
      }),
    ]);

    this.svg = svg;

    // update the area
    svg.select('#areafield').data([data]).attr('d', area);
  }
```

Ответ, найден код отредактирован, всем спасибо!

Comment: А как вы используете ваш класс? Предпологаю, что проблема в использовании.

Comment: объявляю его в React компоненте как const chart = new aggregationChart(dataAr, dateYear); и далее использую методы класса chart.showChart(); и обновление данных chart.updateDataBrush(0, 30, 3, 15, dateNewArray);

Comment: @WindForce, ответы должны быть в ответах, даже если вопрос свой.